# bottom up service generation tool

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Normally I go for top-bottom service creation(e.g. write wsdl, then generate a service based on it)
now I need to generate a service in a bottom-up  - what would be the best tool for it?

I have an old guide which describes generation of ws using   Sun Java Studio Enterprise - it does not exist anymore as I may see... so what is the substitution?

Comment: why dont you use Eclipse IDE for [bottom-up web services](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/BottomUpWebService.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) for creating and using web services.  It's really easy to use and I have never had any big problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java API for XML Web Services ([JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/)) for create Web Services.  JAX-WS uses annotations to simplify the development and deployment of web service clients and endpoints. JAX-WS can be used in Java SE starting with version 6.

There is several JAX-WS implementations:

- [Apache Axis2/Java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)
- [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)
- [Metro](http://jax-ws.java.net/)

You can follow the [JAX-WS Five Minute Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world) of Mohammad Juma. And, why not, [Deploy JAX-WS Web Services On Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/).

For NetBeans and Glassfish, you can see [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html). On eclipse, you can see [Step by Step tutorial to create a JAX-WS with Eclipse, CXF and Glassfish V3](http://al-moayed.de/2011/11/05/step-by-step-tutorial-to-create-a-jax-ws-with-eclipse-and-glassfish-v3/).